# Obtaining a private key through the keytool for app release

Tags: java, android, key, signing

I can't find a tutorial online that gives me the step by step process on how to generate a suitable key using the keytool in the JDK.

This:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

talks about it and gives commands, but it doesn't actually say where and in what folder to key in the commands.  I am sure I am missing something easy here, but could anyone guide me to where I need to start with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run all of these commands in a command prompt.  I am assuming you are using a windows machine to develop with.

Start --> Run --> cmd

type: java -version

You should either get a version number returned like "Java v1.62" or similar or an error "not found"

If you get the version returned on the next line then you can run the keytool command from the prompt you are currently on.

If you get a "not found" error then cd/ into the jdk folder where the keytool command is found.  Run the commands from the prompt found here.

I really reccommend using eclipse to develop.  Eclipse, as part of exporting and signing your app, will create a new keystore from a GUI.  Real simple and easy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't even realize the Eclipse IDE had the way to generate the keystore... I was trying to figure out the command-line arguments for keytool, and was totally befuddled. This helped a LOT!